# How to assign the result of a conditional to a variable in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

There are two django models, "Production" and "Season". Production has a foreign key to Season (i.e. in rails-speak Season has_many Productions, Production belongs_to Season).

I have a detail view for Production, and the page sidebar has the list of all productions in the current season.

```
{% for p in season.production_set.all %}
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center gap-2" href="{% url 'production_detail' season.id p.id %}">
      {{p.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But I would like the nav item to be *disabled* for the current production being viewed. That means adding the 'disabled' class to a element, and setting the "aria-current" attribute as well.

I can use if/else takes, but it ends up being quite verbose and also repetitive, given that I need this logic twice in the same html tag

```
    <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center gap-2 {% if p.id is not production.id %} active {% else %} disabled {% endif %}" aria-current="{% if p.id is production.id %}true{%else%}false{%endif%}" href="{% url 'production_detail' season.id p.id %}">
```

So I tried to assign a variable like

`{% with p.id is not production.id as current %}`

but no syntax I have tried allowed me to assign a boolean expression to a variable.

Is there a way to assign a boolean expression or conditional to a variable in the Django template language?